# How can i use the value to calculate? "10/10"

Tags: javascript

Hi i was wondering if i can make the value 10/10 and 90/100 in 4 different var so i can calculate the avarge?

I tried calling the var with innerHTML, but it doesn't seem to work.

This are the div's:

```
<div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade" smsctip="true">10/10</div>
<div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade">90/100</div>
```

example: 10 + 90 / 10 + 100 => 90.9%. Any suggestion/ideas on how to become this solution?

Comment: Do you have expression in form of string?

Comment: Just in case you are trying to find the average of both, that's not how you calculate it.

Comment: The example actually equals to 119.

Comment: or it could be equal to 1.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var matches = document.querySelectorAll(".course_eval_cell");

let up = 0;
let down = 0;

matches.forEach(function(fraction) {
  var divided = fraction.innerHTML.split("/");
  up += parseInt(divided[0]);
  down += parseInt(divided[1]);
});

console.log((up / down ) * 100 + "%");
```

```html
<div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade" smsctip="true">10/10</div>
<div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade">90/100</div>
```

Comment: Hi, i tried you code and it works almost perfectly. But is there a way to keep the comma? Cause ```parseInt()``` is removing it, and i want to have numbers like ```8.5``` for example.

Comment: just use `parseFloat()` instead

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating your average incorrectly. Get the values by classname and innerText, map over each value and split and divide them accordingly. Then add them together, and divide by how many grades there are, and times by 100 for a percentage:

```js
var grades = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('hasGrade')).map(grade => {
  gradeArr = grade.innerText.split('/')
  return gradeArr[0] / gradeArr[1]
})

var percentage = grades.reduce((acc, grade) => acc + grade, 0) / grades.length * 100 + '%'
console.log(percentage)
```

```html
<div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade" smsctip="true">10/10</div>
<div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade">90/100</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate your average like this.

> 10/10 which is equal to 100/100. by that means the total is 190/200. so the percentage is 95%

```js
var perc = 0;
var count = 0;
$( ".course_eval_cell" ).each(function( index ) {
  perc += eval($( this ).text());
  count = index+1;
});

console.log((perc/count)*100 + "%")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade" smsctip="true">10/10</div>
<div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade">90/100</div>
```

Comment: The system is for school grades and a 8/10 is less powerfull than 80/100.

Comment: So it would be 88 / 110